# Saving plots in folder in R without overlapping

Tags: r, plot

I am currently running my own program in R programming. And I am struggling to figure out the solution for my problem. I have two for loops and I m saving the plots into a folder, first for loop have original data plots and second for loop have contaminated plots. When I run the loop, first iteration doesn't give problem at all, when comes to second iteration the second for loop plots are getting replaced with the one which got in first iteration. Please help me how to sort out this. Your help means a lot to me.

Example:

a consists of 10 3x3 matrices

b consists of 10 3x3 matrices

```
for (i in 1:10)


{


X<- a[i]+b[i]


c<-seq(1:5)/2


for (j in 1:5)


{


b=b+c[j]


X<-a+b


mypath=file.path("D:","R",paste("myplot ", j , ".jpeg")


jpeg(file=mypath)


my title=paste("Plot")


boxplot(b)


dev.off()


}


}
```

Here when I run j loop for i=2 the 5 plots are getting replaced because it again starts numbering from myplot 1,2, etc.

I just want to store all the plots in every i loop with every j loop.

Please help me out

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save all plots for every i and j, you just need to give them different names by including i and j in it:

```
mypath=file.path("D:","R",paste("myplot ", i, j , ".jpeg")
```

Furthermore, to prevent ambiguity and avoid filenames with spaces, I would suggest using:

```
mypath=file.path("D:","R",paste0("myplot_", i,"_", j , ".jpeg")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will try it out.